# Android button margins when background color added

Tags: android, xml, button, android-studio

I have problem with button margins (Android Studio) when I change background colors of buttons. All buttons are the same size but those added background color has no space between them. How can I fix this?

[image: No spaces between buttons with added background color]

This code is for buttons for uncolored buttons

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnAdd"
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnSub"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

And I added this line for get background color on colored buttons.

```
android:background="@color/red"
```

If I delete all background attributes from middle buttons then all buttons looks same same and in sync.

[image: Buttons without background color]

These are the same buttons without this line of code:

```
android:background="@color/red"
```

What should I do to get exactly same button sizes with same margins with background color? No java code involved. Just xml codes above.

Comment: your requirement is not clear, describe further with the layout please

Comment: @DavidJhons I added a couple of lines but let me know if I need to provide more details.

Comment: still not clear, you are saying that, you need space between those +, / , - buttons ? if so place code of those .

Comment: @DavidJhons I added a new image of those buttons without background color. I want to get same look with background color. I don't know what code you are referring to but I used only `android:background="@color/red"` in Button element in layout xml file.

Comment: alright, so just set the button background colour in to red, didnt it worked ?

Comment: No, it's not working the way I wanted. As you can see, there are no empty spaces between with colored buttons. Those transparent margins colored as well.

Comment: @DavidJhons I still don't know the answer!

Comment: @oxyt please tell me you figured this out...I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @oxyt found out you have to use backgroundTint not background